# Linear predictions always the same regardless of features in model

Tags: r, prediction, predict

I'm using the Ames, Iowa housing prices data set.

I have a train set and test set. The test set is missing the dependent variable `SalePrice`. (No column for SalePrice exists).

I have done a linear model and now am trying to predict the Sale Price values on the test set. But when doing so, I always get these same predicted values for SalePrice, regardless of the model used.

Then when trying to calculate RMSE, I get NA.

---

Here is my model:

```
lm2 <- lm(SalePrice ~ 
       GarageCars + 
       Neighborhood + 
       I(OverallQual^2) + OverallQual + 
       OverallQual*GrLivArea + 
       log2(LotArea) + 
       log2(GrLivArea) + 
       KitchenQual +
       I(TotalBsmtSF^2) +
       TotalBsmtSF
       , data=train)

# Add an empty column to the test set, 
# to be later filled in by predictions 
# (Is this even necessary?):
test[, "SalePrice"] <- NA

# My predictions:
predictions <- predict(lm2, newdata = test)
head(predictions)
   1        2        3        4        5        6 
121093.5 170270.7 170029.5 187012.1 239359.2 172962.1
```

I always get these same values regardless of the model used. I suspect I'm just not understanding predict(). I suspect I am only getting the predicted values based on my train set rather than on my test set.

I know that the variable names need to match exactly those used in the model, but what other aspect of predict am I not understanding? Do I need to perform the same predictor variable transformations in the test set? Must I create variables to hold them?

Then I calculate the RMSE:

```
# Formula function for calculating RMSE:
rmse <- function(actual, pred) sqrt(mean((actual-pred)^2))

# Calculate rmse on test set:
rmse(test$SalePrice, predictions))
[1] NA
```

Could you please tell me what I'm doing wrong? Let me know if you need to see the data.

Comment: Need to set 'newdata' to be correctly designed. Read: ?predict.lm

Comment: @Zheyuan Li , I tested removing test$SalePrice column. RMSE is still `NaN`. Should I add it back but as empty, instead of `NA`? How would I do this?

@42- , are you suggesting I use `predict.lm()` instead of `predict()`? Could you please explain why?

What other information would you need to be able to help me with this? I've been stuck on this for over a day and reading the help docs have left me confused.

Comment: So, to correctly design `newdata`, must I create variables in the `test` set containing the transformations performed in my `lm2` model?